# Как сделать загрузку в определенную папку с определенным названием? на Python

Tags: windows, python-3.8

Использовал библиотеку **youtube-dl** на python. Нужно загружать ролик по ссылке в определенную папку с определенным названием, как это сделать? (Моя попытка)

````
ydl_opts = {'outtmpl':'videos_youtube/botazure'} # тут должно задаться путь и название файла
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL() as ydl:
                ydl.download(link) # загрузка ```
````

Comment: Ну почитай документацию, там есть

Comment: так нету документаций

Comment: я вчера впервые узнал об этом модуле и в два щелчка нашел документацию.